# I am try to Pagination using Skip Take in Code Frist Approach But given Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, paging, skip-take

I am trying to Pagination using Skip Take in Code First Approach But given Error.
[image]

**Method**

```
 [HttpPost]
    [Route("Paging")]

    public async ActionResult<IEnumerable<City>> Paging(int CurrentPage)
    {
        CurrentPage = CurrentPage;
        return   _dropdowncontext.cities.OrderBy(x=>x.CityId).Skip((CurrentPage - 1) * 5).Take(5);
    }
```

Comment: `CurrentPage = CurrentPage;`??? Is the `CurrentPage ` also defined as member variable?

Comment: CurrentPage = CurrentPage;  REMOVE THIS

Comment: For a start it would help to paste the exception message text in your question. If the question is "I get an exception." the answer is "You've got a bug." :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Paging")]
public async Task <ActionResult<IQueryable<City>>> Paging(int CurrentPage=1)
    {
    var abc= await _dropdowncontext.cities.OrderBy(x=>x.CityId).Skip((CurrentPage - 1) * 5).Take(5).ToListAsync();

        if (!abc.Any())
            return NotFound();
        return Ok(abc);
    }
```

Comment: You might want to explain this instead of just posting some code.